# How to find out how many people have downloaded from PPAs

Tags: ppa, users, build

How do I find out how many people use a particular PPA.

I see on a particular PPA ;

**Package build summary

A total of 108 builds have been dispatched for this PPA.

Completed builds

108 successful

0 failed**

Does that mean only 108 people have added this PPA to their sources list and installed the package?

Answer (score 10):

This has been a [long-standing request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/139855) and is available if you know about the [Launchpad WebService API](https://help.launchpad.net/API).  This may be available via the standard launchpad webpages but [as yet has not been implemented](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/688141).

> If you are already familiar with the webservice API, then you can use
>   the following binary_package_publishing_history object methods to
>   retrieve the information:
>
> ```
> getDailyDownloadTotals 
> getDownloadCount 
> getDownloadCounts
> ```

[source](http://blog.launchpad.net/cool-new-stuff/tracking-ppa-download-statistics)

---

Linked Blog:

1. http://ftagada.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/ppa-stats-initial-impressions/

Answer (score 4):

No, that means it has built (compiled and packaged) its packages 108 times.

There's no logging in Launchpad that lets you know how many times a package has been downloaded. At least not logging that is publically available.

Answer (score 0):

The popularity contest package included with Ubuntu tracks usage of packages (if the user agrees). If you know the name of a package that is only present in your PPA, you should find this on [their website](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/).